# Traveling from Dublin to Poznan via Stansted

Tags: airport-transfer, london

I need to travel from Dublin to Poznan on a Sunday and am trying to figure out if I would make the transfer in 1 hour 20 minutes, i.e. Dublin flights arrives at 16:50 and the Poznan flights leaves at 18:10. All flights are with Ryanair. As far as I know arriving in Stansted from Dublin is treated as a domestic flight and if that is still the case then according to the Stansted website the following is the case:

> #### Stansted
>
> *If you are connecting from a UK flight to an international flight you will need to pass through special immigration control points where you
> may be asked to show your passport.*

Does anyone know how long it takes to get through this "special immigration"? Is it possible I may need to get a train from my first flight to my second?

Comment: Do you have checked in luggage? That's an important factor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are arriving and departing through Stansted, there is only one terminal so no train will be needed. I don't know if Stansted as an internal mono-rail between airport areas.

As Dublin - Stansted is a journey within what is called the Common Travel Area there are no routine Border Force (Immigration) checks.The 'special immigration ' checks are likely to be conducted by Police for anti-terrorist purposes. (I'm sure you're aware of the Troubles in Northern Ireland over the years.) Unless you are of interest to the Police there shouldn't be a significant delay.

The Common Travel Area is an open borders area formed of UK, Ireland, the Channel Islands and the Isle of Man.

Comment: Stansted has an internal rail for getting to some gates.